Should Terraform be on DevOps instead of Stack Overflow?
There are more than 20k questions related to terraform on Stack Overflow. Terraform isn't a programming language strictly speaking and many questions could be quite dev-opsy.
So, should Terraform continue to be on Stack Overflow and not DevOps?

If the answer is yes... is it even realistic that things would change? It's already a bit of a stretch the tag wiki defines it as a "Tool" used for defining infrastructure as code... but it's hardly even code, it's configuration files. is it in any way even related to programming? It's most certainly devops, but it being on topic somewhere else doesn't make it off topic here so that's not an argument worth pursuing.

elaboration on the "devopsy" argument would be nice. "isn't a programming language" by itself isn't a very strong direction. it's a configuration language. gradle has configuration language. CMake is a configuration language (also kind of procedural). the Rust Manifest Format is a configuration language. (granted- all the examples I've given are build configuration stuff, but I'm not very creative) the list goes on. and several "not programming languages" are considered in-scope, such as HTML and CSS.

I mean... i wouldn't consider most of those programming either, ;) however programming is often used as part of generating html, and css to style it, so those are somewhat within scope. Procuring server resources on the other hand... is editing ini's for skyrim "programming"?

I've said it before and I'll say it again: tags aren't on- or off-topic, questions are. In this case: a DevOps problem can be about the "dev" side or about the "ops" side or anything in between. Stack Overflow takes questions about the "dev" side of a problem, and does not take questions about the "ops" side.

IMO everything dev/ops should be there. The subject of dev/ops is too far removed from programming to really work on a site which is specifically designed for programming problems. It is kind of that weird in between space where you need to have both the developer and the system administrator cap on and you're dipping into the pool of different Stack Exchange sites at the same time. You can try on Stack Overflow and there is a chance you get a good answer, but it's not going to be consistent whether it gets answered or closed. So guaranteed frustrating.

DevOps stuff should definitely be on its own site, but like Karl said, tags themselves aren't on- or off-topic. Yes, 95% of Terraform questions should not be on SO, but questions concerning Terraform provider development can definitely be programming related and also highly domain specific to Terraform.
